# XE8.1: file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64)

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, delphi-xe8

My development environment:
Delphi XE8 Update 1 running on Windows 7 (x64).
XCode 6.4 running on Mac Yosemite 10.10.4.
iOS SDK's are added in XE8 and working fine for both 32 bit/64 bit targets.

When building an iOS app in Delphi with a 64bit iOS target using 64 bit version of libReachability.a obtained from http://delphi.radsoft.com.au/2013/11/checking-for-an-internet-connection-on-mobile-devices-with-delphi-xe5, I get following compile time error:

> [DCC Error] E2597 NYI lto::isObjectFile
>     NYI lto::archName
>     ld: file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): libReachability.a for architecture arm64

This error doesn't come up if the target is iOS 32 bit or iOS simulator. On mac, "lipo -info" on the libReachability.a file used for 64 bit iOS target shows: “Architectures in the fat file: libReachability.a are: armv7 arm64″. It looks OK to me...

The 64 bit libReachability.a file has been copied to Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\lib\iosDevice64\debug directory. Another team member is able to use it just fine but they are on XE8 without the Update 1. Any thoughts on how to fix this error?

Comment: I would say, check that no 32-bit versions of that libReachability file is in the project directory. Clean the project and then recompile.

Comment: That is it!!! I had a 32 bit file lying around in my project diretory (result of having both .32 & .64 files in the proj directory, and renaming to .a before copying over to lib\iOSDevicex directories). Please add your comment as the answer so I could "accpet" it as answer. Thx

Comment: Glad we were able to solve this so quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that all 32-bit versions of libReachability are removed from your project directory.